# AlarmManager setRepeating not working if set repeat two days+

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

Faced with such a problem :

I'm trying to set the repeat in every Monday and Friday at 23:00, but the repeat of works only on Monday.

PendingIntent used in different requestCode. Why is triggered the alarm and notification only on Monday can not understand anyone have any ideas?

AlarmHelper:

```
public class AlarmHelper {

private static AlarmHelper instance;
private Context context;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
Intent intent;




public static AlarmHelper getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new AlarmHelper();
    }
    return instance;
}


public void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}   

public void setAlarm(int day,ModelTask task) {
if (day==Calendar.MONDAY) {
                forDay(2, task);

            }
if (day==Calendar.Friday {
                forDay(6, task);

       }
}


public void forDay(int day, ModelTask task) {

    Calendar  c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);



        Intent  intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", task.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("time_stamp", task.getTimeStamp());
        intent.putExtra("color", task.getPriorityColor());            
        intent.putExtra("numberDay", day);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(),
                day, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);


    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");        
    long timeStamp = intent.getLongExtra("time_stamp", 0);
    int color = intent.getIntExtra("color", 0);
    int numberDay = intent.getIntExtra("numberDay", 0);


    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


    if (MyApplication.isActivityVisible()) {
        resultIntent = intent;
    }

    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, numberDay,
            resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 


    Resources res = context.getResources();


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setContentText(title);
    builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(color));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_white_48dp);


    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;



    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify((int) timeStamp, notification);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your alarmmanager is repeating every  7 days.
You have to change the interval for the wanted days. 
In this line:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
```

You have to change the interval on monday like this:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 4, pendingIntent);
```

And set it on friday again to:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 3, pendingIntent);
```

Hope i could help :)

Comment: Thanks you! Your code fine works! I thought it was enough to set the desired calendar day (c.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);) and repeat will work on this day.

Comment: there was the following problem when the week ends and a new begin, in a new week repeat moves one day forward. Because of what it could be?

Comment: @СебастьянПерейра Dont know, myb it counts on the day of action, that it counts from the following day, and is delayed every week with one day? have no idea :/

Comment: it turns out, if the repeat was on Monday, he will work on Tuesday. If repeat was on Friday, he will work on Saturday :) and after another week, the one that was on Tuesday, work on Wednesday and so on)))) In any case, thank you for your help